# ImportError: No module named 'tflearn'

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I have installed tensorflow following the guide at the website. Tensorflow code runs perfectly, I have also installed tflearn. Problem is whenever I am trying to import tflearn it says "ImportError: No module named 'tflearn'"
but tflearn is there in the site-packages directory

I have an Anaconda installation and a Conda environment for running tensorflow code

Comment: Which site-package directory is `tflearn` in? Is it in the tensorflow virtual environment's site-package directory? Also did you run into any installation error when you were installing `tflearn`?

Comment: I checked using pip show tensorflow and pip show tflearn, this is what I got tflearn location : -/home/sharthakghosh/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages                                                                                                       tensorflow location :- /home/sharthakghosh/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks a lot, it worked. I first uninstalled tflearn, then activated the tensorflow environment and simply did a pip install tflearn. Then installed h5py and scipy after that. It works perfectly now.
Thanks to Zhongyu Kuang for pointing out the difference between the environments.

Comment: i am getting the following error..
ImportError: No module named framework.python.ops

Comment: Not able to install ... following errors are occurring

ImportError: No module named framework.python.ops

Answer (score 10):

Seems to be an Anaconda issue.

```
pip install tflearn
```

was throwing parse errors. This worked for me: open Anaconda prompt

```
conda install pip
pip install tflearn
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution might look very long and wierd, but trust me it doesnt throw any errors/ exceptions. It works perfect.

You could also try doing by activating the virtual env,

For example in my case, I have different environment where I use to work around all ML, NLP code here.

Activate your virtual env first,

```
$ source activate myML-env
```

which will open new environment, like below

```
(myML-env)$
```

Now within this env, hit enter after this below command to install your tflearn package only within this environment.

```
(myML-env)$ pip install tflearn
```

Don't panic if tflearn works well even in python 3.X.
(**NOTE**: Make sure you have tensorflow already installed in this Virtual environment, if not use the same command with the slight change [pip install tensorflow])

Now follow the below command to deactivate the current virtual env,

```
$ source deactivate myML-env
```

Now open your Anaconda >> Environments >> Select myML-env, now open your spyder application from this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I did the following installations

`conda install scipy h5py
pip install tensorflow
pip install tflearn`

I had a warning that a package needed `Cython` but it wasn't installed. So to solve the problem, I did:

`pip install cython
pip install tensorflow
conda install scipy h5py
pip install tflearn`